# Approval Process Test Class

Tags: unit-test, approval-process

I have created a visualforce page which has records of pending approval processes and that page has buttons which approve/ reject a request. 
Please guide how will I have to write test class for it and what will be the steps for it.
So far I have tried creating ProcessInstance which has a required field ProcessDefinitionId and I dont know how to create a Process Definition.

Apex Class :

```
 public approvalProcessWidgetController() 
    {

        listWrapper = new List<WrapperClass>();
        List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> listpiwItem = [SELECT Id, ActorId, OriginalActorId, ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId, ProcessInstance.TargetObject.Name ,ProcessInstance.Status , ProcessInstance.CreatedDate, 
                ProcessInstance.ProcessDefinition.Name, ProcessInstance.ProcessDefinition.TableEnumOrId 
                  FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem];
        if(listpiwItem.size() > 0) {
            for(ProcessInstanceWorkitem piwItem : listpiwItem) {
                listWrapper.add(new WrapperClass(piwItem));
            }
        }
    }
```

Test Class :

```
 public static testMethod void insertOpp(){ 


        Opportunity o = new Opportunity (Name='Test', CloseDate = System.today().addDays(40), StageName = 'Closed Won');
        insert o;
        List<User> user1 = [SELECT Id FROM User Limit 1];





       if(o.StageName == 'Closed Won'){
       approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();     
       req1.setComments('Submitting record for approval.');
       req1.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {UserInfo.getUserId()});
       req1.setObjectId(o.id);
       if(user1!=null)
          req1.setSubmitterId(user1[0].Id);
       //req1.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId('Test_Ani');
       //req1.setSkipEntryCriteria(true);
       approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);
       System.assertEquals('Test',o.Name);


       List<Id> newWorkItemIds = result.getNewWorkitemIds();


        Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req2 = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
        req2.setComments('Approving request.');
        req2.setAction('Approve');
        req2.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {UserInfo.getUserId()});

        // Use the ID from the newly created item to specify the item to be worked
        req2.setWorkitemId(newWorkItemIds.get(0));

        // Submit the request for approval
        Approval.ProcessResult result2 =  Approval.process(req2);

        approvalProcessWidgetController controller = new approvalProcessWidgetController();
        controller.approveIndex = 1;
        controller.approveMass();
        controller.rejectMass();
        controller.approveRequest();

        // approvalProcessWidgetController.WrapperClass objW = new approvalProcessWidgetController.WrapperClass(req2);

       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a `ProcessDefinition` programatically, as far as I know. You would need to query for it by `DeveloperName` if you want to set it, but you can also not set any `ProcessDefinitionId` on your `ProcessSubmitRequest`, in which case when you submit, entry criteria for all `ProcessDefinitions` will be evaluated and your record will enter the first one that applies. This will throw a `DmlException` if none apply.